# Generalisation of the transcendence of $e$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Let $(e_n)$ be a sequence of numbers from the set $\{-1,0,1\}$.

Is it true that
$$\sum\frac{e_n}{n!}$$
is always transcendental except trivial cases (when the series is finite, i.e. $e_n=0$ for almost all $n$)?

Comment: Yes, if the sequence is infinite, then the sum will be transcendental.

Comment: what theorem it follows from?

Comment: Not transcendental, irrational.

Comment: yeah, it is irrational for any bounded sequence of integers except trivial case

Comment: Irrationality just follows from mimicking Euler's proof of the irrationality of $e$ or $1/e$: the $N$-th partial sum multiplied by $N!$ is an integer etc. I am not that sure about trascendence.

Comment: The set of all such sequences is uncountable so almost all of the sums are transcendental.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386701